# android - How to add the view beside the radio button

Tags: android, radio-group

I want to set the view beside the radio button in the radio group. I tried but i am not getting. please can anybody help me.

Source Code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="#FFFFFF">    

    <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:checkedButton="@+id/view_completehistroy_rb"
            android:id="@+id/timeframe_group">

           <!-- View complete history Radio Button -->
           <RadioButton
                android:text="Complete History"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/view_completehistroy_rb"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                />

            <!-- View history using date range Radio Button -->
            <RadioButton
                android:text="From"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                 android:textColor="#000000"
                android:id="@+id/view_daterange_history_rb"/>

        </RadioGroup>

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
          <!--Layout for Time selection  -->
          <LinearLayout 
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
              android:layout_toRightOf="@id/view_daterange_history_rb">                      

               <TextView
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                 android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                 android:text="test1" 
                  android:textColor="#000000"
                 android:textSize="16sp"/>  

                <TextView
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                 android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                 android:text="test2" 
                  android:textColor="#000000"
                 android:textSize="16sp"/>                  
          </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: I thinks its not possible. But if you explain why you need to place it so, we can find out some other method.
I thinks you want to  display two dates there in those textviews. right?

Comment: Here i want to use the daterange option like "from Date picker to DatePicker" thats why

Comment: Based on this comment, the answer by @RahmathullahMPulikkal should be the best solution rather than trying to place a new view next to it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So what about that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="#FFFFFF">    

    <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:checkedButton="@+id/view_completehistroy_rb"
            android:id="@+id/timeframe_group">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/view_completehistroy_rb"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="Complete History"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/view_daterange_history_rb"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/view_completehistroy_rb"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="From"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/view_daterange_history_rb"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/view_daterange_history_rb"
                android:text="test1"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
                android:text="test2"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

On my phone it looks like this:

[image: On my phone it looks like this]

--- some more words to my answer ---

So well, I think the point is a misunderstanding with the LinearLayout. That one does only support placing view Elements in a row.
If you want to have View-Elements that are related to eachother you need the Relative Layout.
The RelativeLayout has a attributes like

```
android:layout_below="@+id/XXXXX"
```

which is a setting for a relative position to other view elements.
So using this you can say that one element (like the TextView) is supposed to be below/above/leftTo/rightTo another view.
That was just the point.
I hope that makes it easier to understand.

Comment: Could you perhaps expand a little bit to explain why this is an answer to the question? I know it probably seems obvious to you, but it's often helpful to explain some code to show what exactly you did.

Comment: Here alignment is working but functionality of radio group is not working means these 2 radio buttons are selected at a time. can u check it once u get clear idea.

Comment: If RadioButtons are not first children of RadioGroup, RadioGroup doesn't work correctly.

Comment: This is not a correct answer. This method ruins the RadioGroups purpose... Selecting the other radio button doesn't deselect the previously selected one.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go. Its not an answer to the question. But it can solve your issue.
YOu can set text of a radio button as follows...

```
RadioButton radBtn=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.view_daterange_history_rb);        
radBtn.setText("From 20/12/2000 to 21/12/2012");
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/timeframe_group"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checkedButton="@+id/view_completehistroy_rb"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- View complete history Radio Button -->

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/view_completehistroy_rb"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Complete History"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <!-- View history using date range Radio Button -->

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/view_daterange_history_rb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="From"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can design a layout in such a way as i have done. Here is the sample layout part :

```
    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/faxPannel"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/emailPannel" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/radioButton"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Label"
                android:textColor="@color/Black"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

And in activity handle the oncheckChanged() event to perform the related functionality. but if you will use RadioGroup in layout, i think it won't be possible for you to achieve what you want.

Note : In above sample where i used TextView you can use any view you want.

Comment: I think Tobias Reich's post can also work but i haven't tried in that way. You can try both.